# Finding a number that is divisible by all numbers from 1 through 10 evenly

Tags: java

I want to find a number that is divisible by all numbers between 1 and 10. My code sample prints out all the numbers that are divisible.  However how would I go about approaching the problem to get just the number that is divisible by ALL numbers from 1 to 10, not just a few:

```
public class prob_5 {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int x = 1; x <= 3000; x++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            if (x % i == 0) {

                System.out.println(x);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Calculate 10 factorial?

Comment: 1260 also works ? Divisible by all 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: @OliCharlesworth While that will find a valid solution, it won't find the lowest such number (2520), and it seems that Purple_Rain is trying to find the lowest such number.

Comment: @GoldRoger `1260 / 8` isn't a whole number.

Comment: @Vulcan: Indeed it won't be the lowest, but the OP doesn't mention that requirement anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that you cannot print inside the inner loop: it is too early. Then figure out when you can print: it's in the outside loop, right after the inner loop.

How do you know that you should print an answer? You need to check that all the MODs of the inner loop have produced no remainder. To do that, add a boolean flag, set it to true outside the inner loop, and set it to `false` if you see a non-zero remainder.

If your flag survives the inner loop without becoming `false`, you've got your answer!

```
boolean isGood = true;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (x % i != 0) {
        isGood = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isGood) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Note: of course there is no point in doing all these checks - all you need is to find the first number by deciding on the smallest number of primary factors that you need to multiply together to get a number that is divisible by all ten numbers, and then print all multiples of that number.

Answer (score 3):

The least common multiple of the values between 1 and 10 is what you are looking for. To do this, all you have to do is multiply each number by the next, so you would have 1*2*3*4...*9*10. This will always give you value that is divisible by all of the numbers in the range.

EDIT: This is exactly what Oli Charlesworth suggested in his comment--10 factorial (10!) is 10*9*8...*3*2*1, which is the same as what I mentioned earlier.

Comment: That won't give the lowest value. If a number is divisible by 2 and 5, it's also divisible by 10.

Comment: The OP was asking for a number that is divisible by ALL numbers between 1 and 10. I don't see how your comment relates to the question?
Besides, that is why I put in the line, "in nearly all cases", because it is occasionally untrue. However, in this case, it will be

Comment: @derstrom8, JB Nizet is referring to your claim that `10!` will give you the lowest value divisible by all of the numbers in the range, which isn't true.  `10!` is 3628800, while the lowest number divisible by 1-10 is 2520.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Sorry, you are right--this will NOT be the lowest value. I just did some extra math and realized that you're right. However, did the OP ask for the lowest option? Using factorial would definitely be the easiest, from a coding perspective

Comment: @derstrom8: what Vulcan said. "least" and "occasionally" have well-defined meanings. In nearly all cases, what you're saying is incorrect. For example, if you have 2 and 3 in the range, then multiplying by 6 is always unnecessary.

Comment: Of course just using n! *does* answer OP's question, but you cannot claim it is the lowest such number

Comment: Fair enough, I will edit my post.

@NiklasB., I never knew about the LCM method! That would have made some of my coding quite a bit easier XD

Comment: There you go everyone, it is fixed. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.test.inter;

/**
 * Class to find the lowest number divisible by 1,2,3...20 * @author Faiz Ahamad
 */
public class TestLowestDivisibleFaiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;
        boolean isDivisible = true;

        for (n = 20; n < 300000000; n++) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                if (n % i != 0) {
                    isDivisible = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    isDivisible = true;
                }
            }
            // If the number is divisible by all break out of the outer loop to
            // get the exact number
            if (isDivisible)
                break;
        }

        // Print if the number is divisible by all
        if (isDivisible) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```